# Finding an unknown PDF and an unknown function, given a relationship between the two and some constraints.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, functions, probability-distributions, systems-of-equations, nash-equilibrium

I'm trying to find unknown PDF f(x;c) and function p(c) that solve

$$p(c)\frac{c}{2} = (1-p(c))\int_0^1 (1-\frac{c}{x+1}) f(x;c)dx \tag{1}$$

for all $c\in [0,1]$. I know that $c$ is continuous and strictly decreasing in $[0,1]$, with $p(0)=1$ and $p(1)=0$. I am also fairly certain that $p(c)=\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{P_n(c)}{Q_n(c)}$ where $(P_n)_{n\geq 1}$ and $(Q_n)_{n\geq 1}$ are unknown sequences of n-degree polynomials.

Additionally, $(1)$ is actually a special case of

$$p(c)\frac{ct}{t+1} = (1-p(c))\int_{1-t}^1 (1-\frac{ct}{x+t}) f(x;c) dx$$

valid for $t\in [0,1]$, where $t=1$ in $(1)$. I presented $(1)$ first because my hunch was that it would be an easier solve, though it may be underspecified on its own.

I also know that $f(0;c) \to \infty$ as $c \to 1$, and $f(1;c) \to 2$ as $c \to 0$. That is, $f(x;c)$ collapses to a PMF at $c=1$.

The last thing I have is a (numerically generated) plot of $p(c)$. I can also generate plots of $f(x;c)$ for any given $c$. ($c=0.25,0.5,0.75$ attached).

[$p(c)$ vs $c$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0Zzn.png)

[$f(x;c), c=0.25$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LnG4k.png)

[$f(x;c), c=0.50$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gA98p.png)

[$f(x;c), c=0.75$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cwMr1.png)

This is an attempt at computing a Nash Equilibrium for a (dis)continuous game. Any help at all would be tremendously appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Why in the $c = 0$ case does $f(x,0)$ need to be specified at all?. Further if it is a PDF, why would this specification that it is 0 everywhere except at $x = 1$ make it a valid PDF?

Comment: There is some sort of limiting behavior in that $f(x,c)$ collapses into a PMF at $c=0,1$. At $c=\epsilon, 1-\epsilon$ it is still a PDF though, peaked close to $x=1-c$. I am not sure if this also answers your first question. Thank you

Comment: It does not answer my question. From your equation (1), setting $c = 0$ lets both LHS and RHS be 0 independent of the integral (provided the integral is bounded), I do not see why $c = 0$ enforces the condition that $f(x,0) = 0$ everywhere except at the $x = 1$. Further, if this is a true PDF, shouldn't $\int_0^1 f(x,0) \ dx = 1$. Does it in this case?

Comment: Now that you mention it, I had a mistake in the original write-up. It would be more accurate to say that $f(1,c) \to \infty$ as $c \to 0$, and $f(0,c) \to \infty$ as $c \to 1$. Thanks for pointing this out. $c=0$ doesn't 'enforce' anything insomuch as it is a constraint imposed on / a characteristic of the functions $f(x;c)$ and $p(c)$.

As for the other point, in that sense f(x;0) does not need to be specified, but this does not invalidate the equation. If anything, it provides a sanity check that the equation is correct.

Comment: Would you be very nice to briefly explain the relation of this function to Nash equilibrium?